# How to process regression using random forest in Accord.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, regression, random-forest, accord.net

I found that C# framework Accord.NET supports random forest model calculation. But I've found only examples with classification. How can I make a random forest regression using this framework, if it's, of course, possible?

Comment: I am also looking for this now. Did you end up finding an example for Accord.Net RandomForest Regression?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [page](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_DecisionTrees_RandomForest.htm): it is not possible. Each method Decide as output "Computes a class-label decision for a given input".
Also [here](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/432) you can see that Accord net would like to have regression implemented from February 2017 and wait for a pull request, but looks like there is not yet any implementation of it.